Gettting error "The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3)." on gradlew genSources
I am new to Java, Minecraft modding, and Linux Mint.
I am trying to build this in IntelliJ IDEA with the command ./gradlew genSources and getting this error: The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used.
I have tried setting various protocols in gradle.properties, such as
https.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
But this is still not working.

It seems like maybe a package on your operating system may be out of date, causing this TLS issue. Even though you are getting this problem I wouldn't think it would affect connecting to servers if you are. At worst maybe impact querying data from servers or something like that. Check if all of your libraries on your linux operating system are up to date, because that what I think the case it.
Best of luck!
